# IdentityServer4 database migration issue

Tags: c#, migration, identityserver4, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-identity

I'm building identityserver4 using .net core 3.1. I'm using database migration to build the database. The issue I'm having is the seeding method. My seeding method is as follows:

```
private void ClientSeed(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<ApiResource>()
               .HasData(
                   new ApiResource
                   {
                       Name = "PatientPortalAPI",
                       DisplayName = "Patient Portal API",

                       ApiSecrets =
                       {
                           new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                       },

                       Scopes =
                       {
                           new Scope()
                           {
                                 Name = StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                                 DisplayName = StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                                 Description = null,
                                 Required = false,
                                 Emphasize = false,
                                 ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                           },
                           new Scope()
                           {
                                 Name = StandardScopes.OpenId,
                                 DisplayName = StandardScopes.OpenId,
                                 Description = null,
                                 Required = false,
                                 Emphasize = false,
                                 ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                           }
                       }
                   }
               );

            builder.Entity<IdentityResource>().HasData(
                    new IdentityResource()
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Name = "openid",
                        DisplayName = "Your user identifier",
                        Description = null,
                        Required = true,
                        Emphasize = false,
                        ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                    },
                    new IdentityResource()
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Name = "profile",
                        DisplayName = "User profile",
                        Description = "Your user profile information (first name, last name, etc.)",
                        Required = false,
                        Emphasize = true,
                        ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                    });

            builder.Entity<Client>()
                .HasData(
                    new Client
                    {
                        ClientId = "t8agr5xKt4$3",
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

                        ClientSecrets =
                        {
                            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                        },

                        AllowedScopes =
                        {
                            StandardScopes.OpenId,
                            StandardScopes.Profile,
                            StandardScopes.Email,
                            StandardScopes.Address,
                            "api1",
                            StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
                        },

                        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                        RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                        RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
                    });
        }
```

The error I'm getting when I add migration is this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Claim'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'reader' in 'Claim(BinaryReader reader)'; cannot bind 'reader', 'subject' in 'Claim(BinaryReader reader, ClaimsIdentity subject)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value' in 'Claim(string type, string value)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value', 'valueType' in 'Claim(string type, string value, string valueType)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer' in 'Claim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer' in 'Claim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer', 'subject' in 'Claim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer', 'subject', 'propertyKey', 'propertyValue' in 'Claim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, string propertyKey, string propertyValue)'; cannot bind 'other' in 'Claim(Claim other)'; cannot bind 'other', 'subject' in 'Claim(Claim other, ClaimsIdentity subject)'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConstructorBindingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Claim'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'reader' in 'Claim(BinaryReader reader)'; cannot bind 'reader', 'subject' in 'Claim(BinaryReader reader, ClaimsIdentity subject)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value' in 'Claim(string type, string value)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value', 'valueType' in 'Claim(string type, string value, string valueType)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer' in 'Claim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer' in 'Claim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer', 'subject' in 'Claim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject)'; cannot bind 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer', 'subject', 'propertyKey', 'propertyValue' in 'Claim(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, string propertyKey, string propertyValue)'; cannot bind 'other' in 'Claim(Claim other)'; cannot bind 'other', 'subject' in 'Claim(Claim other, ClaimsIdentity subject)'.
```

Excluding the above seeding method, database migration works really well. As soon as I call the seeding method in OnModelCreating method in ConfigurationDbContext class it fails with the above error.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong here???

I'll be looking forward for all your replies.

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Are you definitely using the DB entity classes here and not the framework model types? Also, I don't think it's neccessary to add those scopes to that ApiResource.

Comment: Hi Mackie, thank you so much for your message. I am using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities and not model types. I'm trying to get refresh token to work. Based on my knowledge I need to add offline_access scope to get refresh token

Comment: The reason I asked as it's clearly trying to do something with the standard framework Claim type which would not be referenced by the EF models. AllowOfflineAccess on the Client config is the thing that enables refresh tokens. You also have to use a token-endpoint based flow like hybrid or authorization_code for it to work.

Comment: Hello Mackie I set AllowOfflineAccess to true and also consumed token endpoint with authorization_code still didn't work. I'm getting 400 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use types on `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities`, you have a mix of models and entities in code, try to remove `using IdentityServer4.Models;` to get a clear understanding of what is entity and what is model. Once you used entities properly you will see that for example `ApiResource` doesn't have a property as `ApiSecrets`, it is `Secrets`.

There is another way to do initialize the DB by adding a method ob `startup.cs`, sth like:

```
private void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

        var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
        context.Database.Migrate();
        if (!context.Clients.Any())
        {
            foreach (var client in Config.Clients)
            {
                context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (!context.IdentityResources.Any())
        {
            foreach (var resource in Config.Ids)
            {
                context.IdentityResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (!context.ApiResources.Any())
        {
            foreach (var resource in Config.Apis)
            {
                context.ApiResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like this;

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // this will do the initial DB population
    InitializeDatabase(app);

    // the rest of the code that was already here
    // ...
}
```

Read more [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_entityframework.html#initializing-the-database)